# Oracle Join Condition with Top 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I've tried to find a solution to this including the use of the row_number() method within my join, but somehow can't get the desired outcome.

The issue I'm having right now is based on the fact that I have some records from the join table that have multiple instances (1 to many) with the same criteria which is causing duplicates, so even though I thought I could use a min() or max() on a date, the cases where I have the same **EffectDT** come out twice.

**In addition to this**, if I have instances where I don't have an "active" record (XPIRDT IS NOT NULL), I need to pull the expired record, so would I use "OR" statement or simply perform another join to get the expired record in the event the first join doesn't produce any record and have a case condition to evaluate the value before display?

So here's an instance of sample data I'm dealing with:

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

So the following with the above data sample still produces 2 records, which I can eliminate one by evaluating the expiry date, **BUT** will present problems if all the records are expired so won't retrieve anything.

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTYXREF
      ON MBR_PERSON.NAMEID = PARTYXREF.NAMEID
     AND PARTYXREF.REFTYPE LIKE 'COMM'
 LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT *
                FROM ADDRDATA TMP
                WHERE TMP.ADDRTYPE = '2'
                AND TMP.EFFECTDT = (SELECT MAX(EFFECTDT) FROM ADDRDATA TMP2 WHERE TMP2.ADDRID = TMP.ADDRID)
             )  MBR_ADDR
       ON PARTYXREF.REFKEY = MBR_ADDR.ADDRID
```

I've also tried using the following within my "JOIN" statement, however I somehow can't make use of the joining key (REFKEY) within where I have the value hardcoded here, so this actually does work, but can't seem to incorporate in the join statement.

```
SELECT ADDR.*
FROM (SELECT tmp.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY XPIRDT DESC) AS SEQNUM
        FROM ADDRDATA tmp
        WHERE tmp.ADDRTYPE = '2'
          AND tmp.ADDRID = 10948448
       ) ADDR
WHERE SEQNUM = 1
```

I've wasted one hour too many on this, so I need someone else outlook please! :)

Comment: You're using `ROW_NUMBER` function wrongly. You should also partition your data by your other columns (so the `ROW_NUMBER` function could sort rows meeting some criteria by your date) - example `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADDRID, EFFECTDT ORDER BY XPIRD DESC)`. Eventually, similar `DENSE_RANK` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not clear which record, in your example, you wanted, so let me give you some alternatives.

I gathered from your problem statement that you want the latest effective date of those available.  Since there are ties involved, you cannot use `max()` (as you've already stated), and `row_number()` is the way to go:

```
with cte as (
  select
    addrid, effectdt, xpirdt,
    row_number() over (partition by addrid order by effectdt desc) as rn
  from addrdata
)
select
  addrid, effectdt, xpirdt
from cte
where rn = 1
```

The next part was where you lost me with the nulls...  If your secondary sort is by expiration date and you want a null value to trump the latest expiration date, then you would order by the expiration date and put `nulls first`:

```
with cte as (
  select
    addrid, effectdt, xpirdt,
    row_number() over 
        (partition by addrid order by effectdt desc, xpirdt nulls first) as rn
  from addrdata
)
select
  addrid, effectdt, xpirdt
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Which means this row is the winner:

```
10948448    5/14/2015   <null>
```

If, however, you wanted nulls to be considered only if there are no expiration dates, you can use `nulls last` (or omit it, as it is the default):

```
with cte as (
  select
    addrid, effectdt, xpirdt,
    row_number() over
        (partition by addrid order by effectdt desc, xpirdt nulls last) as rn
  from addrdata
)
select
  addrid, effectdt, xpirdt
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Meaning this guy has won the prize:

```
10948448    5/14/2015   5/13/2015
```

Since this uses `row_number()` you will not lose any rows -- each row is guaranteed to have a row number.  It's just that if there are true ties, then it's a toss-up as to which row is chosen.  However, your issue with null expiration dates should not cause any problems with this approach.

-- edit 2/13/16 --

I think I'm *starting* to understand your issue, but I'm not 100% sure.  I've incorporated snippets of your code with the left join with my suggestion, and the need to have null expiration dates first, and this is my next crack:

```
with cte as (
  select
    addrid, effectdt, xpirdt,
    row_number() over 
        (partition by addrid order by effectdt desc, xpirdt nulls first) as rn
  from addrdata
)
select
  cte.addrid, effectdt, xpirdt
from
  mbr_person mb
  left join partyxref px on
    mb.nameid = px.nameid and
    px.reftype = 'COMM'
  left join cte on
    px.refkey = cte.addrid and
    cte.rn = 1
```

Assuming this doesn't do it:

1. When you say a null XPIRDT takes precedence -- do you mean even over more recent effective dates, or is it only a tiebreaker for the most recent EFFECTDT?  If the latter, then what I have should work.  If the former, then we need to switch the order by's in the analytic function
2. I am totally guessing when it comes to the `partyxref` and `mbr_person` tables.  If this doesn't cut it, maybe post some sample data and desired output for including those two tables, or fiddle it?

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes, the NULL XPIRDT will take precedence on any other record as it's considered the "active" one, however in the event I don't have any active records, I'd pull the expired one next by EFFECTDT.   As far as your suggestions, would you be able to provide the statement using the LEFT JOIN on ADDRID?   I tried a few variations by trying to account for it within the sub-select producing the record, but somehow I just kept getting no rows back as I assume the row number takes precedence on the set of records I'm trying to retrieve before establishing the row sequence.

Comment: My second attempt is posted...  and I have some potential follow-up questions in the likely event that's not 100% addressing your question either

Comment: Thanks again!!  Given the amount of records involved, I actually populated a global temp with the distinct addresses using the method you suggested, which I then join the temp table to my main query to fetch the address data. Ran several tests this morning based on the scenarios given and everything appears to work perfectly!  Thank you!!